Route to a default child of a parent route unless another child is already active
My Angular application has three items on its main navigation bar, "One", "Two", and "Three". When I choose "Two", the loaded component has four tabs, say "Ay", "Bee", "Cee", and "Dee" that route to child routes of the route for "Two". Under the tabs is a nested router-outlet where the child route goes. When I click Two, I want the first tab to be the "active" one and display the component for Two Ay in the router-outlet unless the currently activated route is another child is another child of Two. In that case, I want the view to remain as is. In other words, I want the "Two" item to take the user to Two Ay only if the user is currently on One or Three, and do nothing otherwise.
The routes:
export const routeConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: OneComponent },
  {
    path: 'two',
    component: TwoComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'ay', component: TwoAyComponent },
      { path: 'bee', component: TwoBeeComponent },
      { path: 'cee', component: TwoCeeComponent },
      { path: 'dee', component: TwoDeeComponent },
    ],
  },
  { path: 'three', pathMatch: 'full', component: ThreeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

The three navigation bar items route to '/', '/two/ay', and '/three', respectively.
Inside two.component.html I have the tabs and router-outlet as follows:
<nav ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
  <a ngbNavLink class="nav-link nav-item" [routerLink]="['/two/ay']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
    Ay
  </a>
  <a ngbNavLink class="nav-link nav-item" [routerLink]="['/two/bee']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
    Bee
  </a>
  <a ngbNavLink class="nav-link nav-item" [routerLink]="['/two/cee']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
    Cee
  </a>
  <a ngbNavLink class="nav-link nav-item" [routerLink]="['/two/dee']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
    Dee
  </a>
</nav>
<div class="p-3 border-start border-end border-bottom">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

Is there a way to alter this to make the route for "Two" conditional on whether or not one of its children is the currently activated route?

When you directly navigate to two, then the child route will be '', you just need to redirect to ay when this happens.
export const routeConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: OneComponent },
  {
    path: 'two',
    component: TwoComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'ay', pathMatch: 'full' }, // <- changed here!
      { path: 'ay', component: TwoAyComponent },
      { path: 'bee', component: TwoBeeComponent },
      { path: 'cee', component: TwoCeeComponent },
      { path: 'dee', component: TwoDeeComponent },
    ],
  },
  { path: 'three', pathMatch: 'full', component: ThreeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

